# SQL Server database growth issue

Tags: sql-server

I made a mistake in my logic and let a table grow way beyond what it should have. Now the database is 90gb (where it should be 10gb). I was able to clear the table that had all this information but I can't get the database to shrink.

I've used `dbcc shrinkDatabase` and `dbcc shrinkfile` and it appears to shrink the database down to 82gb temporarily but then goes right back to 90gb after a minute or so. I'm positive that another table is not taking up the space.

Also, if I export the DB it's only about 5gb in size.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with the indexes because it happens right after I run the rebuild on the index (the application is offline so nothing is being written to the database while I am working on it).

For a location this size using my application it's typical to have 8-10gb of DB file usage.

Does anyone know how to shrink the DB back to its normal size?

Comment: By "db size", what exactly are you measuring? Do you include the transaction log in this size?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that; it's 3gb for the transaction log

Comment: Oh, and the size is related to the physical file size on the server.

Comment: Generally, when you delete from a table, the space is not returned for the table, or indexes, back to the database. So look up shrinking or reorganizing the table & indexes. Then shrink the database/files.

Comment: Could you include the (redacted as required) output of "exec sp_spaceused" and "select * from sys.sysfiles" in your question, this may help identify further questions or answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shannon I got my answer.  I needed to run the following to clean the table up
dbcc cleantable('databasename',tablename)
dbcc shrinkdatabase('databasebame', 10)

I then tried to rebuild the clustered index on the table to no avail (probably because the table had grown so large; it was very much fubar) so I dropped and re-created the index.

The space came to what I was expecting to see.